# Activate virtual environment in windows using Git-Bash

Tags: python, virtualenv, git-bash

I am trying to activate virtual environment in windows using Git-Bash
I used this line and this works fine

```
virtualenv project1_env
```

Then when trying this line to activate

```
.\project1_env\Scripts\activate
```

I got bash: .project1_envScriptsactivate: command not found
I tried several tries to make it works but it didn't

Note that this line works on command prompt with no problem
So my problem is with Git-Bash on windows

Thanks advanced for help

Comment: `source project1_env/Scripts/activate` -- forward slashes instead of backslashes (a more succinct form is `. project1_env/Scripts/activate` -- here the space is important)

Comment: That's great and awesome. Thanks a lot for great help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On Windows10, you could go in the directory of your virtualenv where the Scripts folder is placed then enter the below command

```
source ./Scripts/activate
```

Comment: after this command has activated the `(base)` environment, you can activate other conda virtual environments with the usual conda syntax: `conda activate <my_venv_name>`